# Problem when Installing Canon Pixma IP2770 Driver

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

In my Ubuntu 13.10 system, I tried to install **Canon Pixma IP2770** with the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip2700series
```

Then I get the following error messages like this:

```
cnijfilter-common:i386 : Depends: libpopt0:i386 (>= 1.7) but it is not going to be installed
cnijfilter-ip2700series:i386 : Depends: libatk1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libcairo2:i386 (>= 1.0.2-2) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libpango1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.12.3) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libpopt0:i386 (>= 1.7) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libtiff4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

Can someone help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following commands ;

```
sudo apt-get remove libpopt0 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libgtk2.0-0 libpango1.0-0 libpopt0 libtiff4

sudo apt-get --install-suggests --install-recommends install cnijfilter-ip2700series
```